# Как реализовать слагирование в DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

СУТЬ ВОПРОСА : `lorem.com/category_slug/`

Должен возвращать на фронт queryset product отфильтрованный по category__slug='category_slug'. Как это реализовать?
В пример желаемого поведения хочу привести каталог 21vek.by

**Модели Product, Category. Отношение M2M.**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    parental_category = models.ManyToManyField('self', 
                                                blank=True,
                                                verbose_name='Категория-родитель',
                                                )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True,
                            verbose_name='Название')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, 
                                 related_name='category',
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True,
                                 verbose_name='Категория',
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Serializers**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id','name','slug',
                  'category']

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name', 'parental_category']
```

Comment: документацию по фильтрации в DRF читали? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Не уверен. Сейчас прочту.